# Checkbox select all logic react js.How to unselect one by one afterwards?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, local-storage

As per title I am implementing a checkbox that select all checkboxes and it works but when I am unselecting one by one the check remains on the current row and vanish on the others.

NOTE ABOUT LOGIC: I have a separate component where I have my single checkbox to select all and with that checked I set a boolean variable in the localstorage to be read in another component.

principalCheckbox code:

```
function handleChange() {
    if (checked === false) {
        localStorage.setItem('selectAllChecked', String(true))
        dispatch(reduxActions.selectAll())
        setChecked(true)
    } else {
        dispatch(reduxActions.clearSelection())
        localStorage.setItem('selectAllChecked', String(false))
        setChecked(false)
    }
}

<input type='checkbox' checked={checked} onChange={handleChange} />
```

Single checkboxes logic

```
<input 
    type='checkbox' 
    checked={checked ? checked : areAllSelected} 
    onChange={handleChange} 
/>
```

Let us analyze that condition {checked ?checked : areAllSelected}:

case1:so checked initially is false(nothing is selected so it goes in the else->but are allselected is also false so initially nothing is selected->OK)

case2: i click on single checkboxes so checked exist and the value is that "checked" so the single item is correctly selected->ok

case3: I click on selectAll and previously there was nothing checked so the condition go to the else and are all selected -OK

case4: same of case 3 ,I select everything but then when I click on single row the value of selectAll is false and the one of the single row is true (but previously was also checked) and it remains checked while should be deselected

Any ideas on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to rework you logic.

The select/unselect of the "all" checkbox should trigger a true change in all items to selected or unselected.

The actual state of the "all" checkbox should be computed by the state of the rest of the "single" checkboxes.

Comment: how can I do that If the way to change the checkbox is onChange(so if I click on the selected checkbox) or "checked" attribute? like in my code I made it dependant both by the allSelected and by the current selection checked={checked ? checked : areAllSelected}

Comment: @javaFE you should have a list with the checkboxes, right ? When you click each you should update this list and mark the specified checkbox as `checked`. When clicking the "all" you should then update all the checkboxes in the list to be `checked` (or `unchecked`). The to see if the "all" checkbox should be checked, you can do a `const allSelected = checkboxList.every( checkbox => checkbox.checked === true )` (*or somilar according to your variable/property names and list/object structure*).

Comment: if you could post more relevant parts of your code, i could suggest more detailed examples.

Comment: Actually I have 1 checkbox that is created everytime I create a new row.My main issue is to make the checked property dependant globally by both all selected checkbox and single check on single checkbox